# RTL navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Is there any way to change `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` text direction from right to left?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do that. You have to do it manually.

Comment: thx for ur answer. but what do u mean Manually?